# Is there a quirky way to have outgoing requests with static IP from AWS lambda running in VPC without using NAT gateway or NAT instance?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, ip, amazon-vpc, whitelist

Static EIP can be requirement can be obtained through either using NAT Gateway or a NAT instance but in this specific requirement, these both are not allowed. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible AFAIK.  If you're running in a VPC you need a NAT (either gateway or instance) to route traffic external to the VPC since it's not possible to attach an EIP directly to a lambda function.  I assume they don't allow that because an EIP can only be attached to one network interface at a time.  Because of how there can be multiple instances of the same Lambda function running at one time it wouldn't be possible for them to share one single EIP.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

If you're not running in a VPC then you will get an external IP but that IP will change each time a new lambda context (instance) is created.  You can make this happen less often by keeping the function warm, i.e. calling it every 5 mins or so, so the function context doesn't get removed as often.  But, this doesn't completely prevent the context from being recreated (or from multiple instances running at the same time) so that won't solve your issue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html

https://www.serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm

EDIT: Some larger companies don't allow NATs because they route all traffic through their own firewalls to be able to monitor traffic.  If that's the case then you might not have to do anything, depending on how routing is setup.  If the VPC/subnet routes external traffic through the company firewall then it may just work or you might have to talk with the networking group at your company.  Make sure your lambda function is running in a subnet that is routing 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to a gateway.

Comment: Thanks @JeffR for clarifying the options.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented HAProxy on EC2, lambda calls HAProxy instance which calls external system, solved.